# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'harfang'

Tags: python-3.x, pip

PLEASE ,how to import harfang in ubunto for python3 ,?? it doesn't install for me !!

i tryed pip install harfang and doesn't work

Comment: `pip` may be `pip2` by default, try using `pip3 install harfang`

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install harfang`

Comment: it dosn't work  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for harfang
Failed to build harfang
ERROR: Could not build wheels for harfang, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Could you please post the entire error message?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

The solution is to simply use

```bash
pip3 install harfang
```

or

```bash
python3 -m pip install harfang
```

If it throws error regarding pip not being installed, you can install `python3-pip` using **apt**.

### Explanation

Why you were unable to install with **pip** directly and instead had to use **pip3** is because, in **ubuntu**, the default python version is `python 2.x`. The current python versions actively maintained and supported is `3.x` where x means some minor version.

Due to this reason, after you install a `python 3.x` installation, you need to specify if it's **python3** or **python2**, where **python** is a default alias for **python2**.

I also mentioned about `python3 -m pip install harfang`. This also works, as `python3 -m pip` means trying to run a python module using specific python installation (which in our case is python3), you can specify which module to call using `-m`. You can do it with any other installed python module which has a CLI interface as well.